# deploy project Node on VPS

Tags: angularjs

i try to deploy my project on my vps.

This is my server.js

> var http = require('http');
>      var fs = require('fs');
>      var mime = require('mime');
>
> var filename = "./index.html";
>
> http.createServer(function (req, res) {
>
> ```
>  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, file) {
>    if (err) {
>      res.end("errore ci fu");
>    }
>
>    res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": require('mime').lookup(filename) });
>    res.write(file, 'binary');
>    res.end();
>
>  });
> ```
>
> }).listen(5000);
>
> console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/');

and this is my structure:

[image]

this is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS User Registration and Login Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="app-content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" ng-if="flash" ng-bind="flash.message"></div>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="credits text-center">
        <p>
            <a href="http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx">AngularJS User Registration and Login Example</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://jasonwatmore.com">JasonWatmore.com</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app-services/authentication.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app-services/flash.service.js"></script>

    <script src="app-services/user.service.local-storage.js"></script>

    <script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="login/login.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="register/register.controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try tu run application e I on my browser type the right address, the responce is an error because it deasn't download tha angular js and maybe also other dependencies.

this is the result on my browser:

[image]

Why it doesn't download the dependencies?????

I ask for your help!!

Thanks

Comment: Ok I understand that in this example, is not managed the other request after the index.html: for example for css e js files...